# assign individual value to text field with same class name using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get value from "data-val" input field which is hypen separated and after removimg hypen  individual value  should get assigned to separate text box which have same class name,  but instead of separate value only last value is assigning to every text box.

for example if data-val class have value like this   3-4-5 then it should get separated by "-" and individual value get assigned to separated text filed.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control data-val" onblur="assign_val('data-val','input_val')"value=""/>

<input type="text" class="form-control input_val" name="">

 <input type="text" class="form-control input_val"  name="">

<input type="text" class="form-control input_val"  name="">

<script>

    function assign_val(data-val,input_val) {

            var data-val = $(".data-val").val(); 

            var count = $('.' + input_val).length;
            var i;
            var data-val= data-val.split("-");  

            for (i = 1; i <= data-val.length; i++)
            {

              $(".input_val").val(data-val[i]);
            }

        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using JQuery .each https://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$( ".input_val" ).each(function( index ) {
  $(this).val(data-val[index]);
});
```